# Application crashes on client computer

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, debugging

I have send my client an application. When he clicks on a special button the whole application crashes. I've uploaded all *.pdb files in the same folder of the *.exe files and he installed Visual Studio Express 2010.

None of the solutions helps to get any information of the crash. No "details" button or stack situation. I am not able to debug the application. Only the message "program will close now" without any additional note of "where the fault could be".

[image: Error message]
On windows error report there is logged the file "Error in application -my application- in module MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll. But this dll is not the problem. I've reinstalled the framework but could not see any improvements. Same crash as before.

**How to debug an application when it is installed on client computer?**

*

> At the current state none of the answers could be used on clients computer. I have it
>   now in the office and installed visual studio. When compiling that way it works. The
>   question is why.
>    *

Comment: from the sound of things, this is a reproducible bug on the client's end. If so, is it then reproducible on yours? If not, the client's environment is to blame, and you are reduced to locating all interaction points of your program with the environment downstream from that button click and ensuring those elements are the same. If it is reproducible on your end, debug it

Comment: Wrap a `try/catch` block of code around your entire Button.Click method, and output the Exception message and stack trace to a text file. That should give you a better idea about what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you sending a Setup to him or the executable.

Comment: On my side, there is no crash. Only on clients machine. But the client has a complete new computer with fresh Win7. I need to fix this. There is no try/catch block because it is some milliseconds after the click and contains several asynchronous procedures. I need the way to get the stack or details of crash.

Comment: Rachel has already told you how to get the stack trace; output it to a text file in the `catch` clause. If you have several asynchronous procedures you have to do this in every one.

Comment: Since you have the PDBs and Visual Studio installed on the client machine, Set up the Visual Studio to Break on All exceptions (shouldn't really be necessary since this scenario is an unhandled..) then with the application running, use Debug/Attach To Process in VS to attach to the running instance. Click your special button and VS should break on whatever threw. My guess would be based on what you describe that one of your async methods is making an assumption about the runtime environment and throwing an unhandled exception in the worker thread, thus crashing your app.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the client's machine, then you can install the "Debugging Tools For Windows" for free from Microsoft. It includes several debuggers, including WinDbg. You can use its GFlags tool to set the client's system to start up the debugger of your choice (I recommend WinDbg as its capabilities are much greater than Visual Studio) when your application starts, or capture dump files whenever you application exits or crashes. If you have network connectivity to your client's machine, you can use its debuggers to remote debug your client's machine.

Using GFlags, you can set the client's system to trap any crashes or thread exits of any kind to create a dump automatically for you, to whatever folder you specify for whatever application or process you want. So even if you can't use the client's machine for direct debugging, you can still capture dumps from your application crashing with minimum effort. Just install "Debugging Tools For Windows" on the client's machine, use GFlags to set the options you need (look under "Silent Process Exit" tab for setting up dump file creation options), and collect your dumps if that's what you are after.

You can get "Debugging Tools For Windows" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) can launch a process and then monitor it for exceptions: `C:\>procdump -e 1 -f "" -x c:\dumps consume.exe`. You can [launch the Debugger automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) you can capture last operation and relevant stack trace before app crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the tools below to track and debug silent app crashes on client computers. Some of the tools required access to the client's computer.

- [Procdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump)
- [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools)
- [DumpChk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dumpchk)
- [Sentry](https://sentry.io/)
- Windows Event Viewer

Answer (score -1):

If for some reason you can't reproduce the bug on your workstation and you want to debug an application running on the client's computer, your best tool is the Visual Studio Remote Debugger.
You need to keep `.pdb` files to make it work though.

More information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx